# Google Drive API 'exportLinks' not available for some Google Files

Tags: google-drive-api

There are few Google Files in Google Workspace drives that when access via API [files:get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) does not show the 'exportLinks' property. I'm accessing the API as the file owner user. Also, this file sends 'exportSizeLimitExceeded' (This file is too large to be exported) error when tried to export file by [files:export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) API method as the file owner user. I'm using the scope 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' when accessing the API.

For such large Google Files which can't export due to error  "exportSizeLimitExceeded", I get 'export_links' URLs and pick the URL based on the export format required and do download the file by following redirections. This worked for all of the tested large Google File scenarios, but when the 'exportLinks' is not available I can't perform the download like this.

Appreciate it if we can point what could be the reason for not having 'exportLinks' property.

Comment: If you want to download docs, sheets or slides, there seems to file size limit of 10mb. Optionally you can also try using https://rclone.org/drive/ which creates wrapper for several extra params

Comment: Yes, there are some size limitations and this file is getting 'exportSizeLimitExceeded'  meaning it's larger than that. But I've tested with many other large Google Files, but those had the 'exportLinks' property, so I was able to download those large files by 'exportLinks' of the required export format.
Thats why  'exportLinks' is important for me for these large Google Files.

Comment: What kind of file are you trying to download (document, spreadsheet, etc.)? If you try to get all the `exportLinks` (not only for the exact mime type you desire), are there any?

Comment: I'm accessing lot of 3rd party Google Drive data via API. Seems this is happening for Google Form files. Question for me is why and when is this happening, can it happen to other Google File types to understand the scenario here..

Comment: What would the local version of Forms be? I can't think of an offline equivalent for them.

Comment: Also, are we talking about Google Workspace files (docs, sheets, forms, etc)? Or files on your Drive in general?